# Bitbucket pipelines with docker image using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, bitbucket-pipelines, docker-image

I want to perform Continuous Integration using Bitbucket Pipelines to build my project.
I first used bitbucket-pipeline.yml file with default configuration as shown below:

```
image: php:7.1.29
pipelines:
default:


- step:
    caches:
      - composer
    script:
      - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip
      - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
      - composer install
      - vendor/bin/phpunit
```

After committing and running the test, it failed.

I modified the above configuration with the one below to test the database as well:

```
image: phpunit/phpunit:6.5.3

pipelines:
default:
- step:
  caches:
  - composer
  script:
  - apk add --no-cache php7-gd php7-xmlwriter
  - php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.testing', '.env');"
  - composer install
  - php artisan key:generate
  - php artisan migrate --seed
  - vendor/bin/phpunitenter
```

But when I tried to run it again, it failed. I have now 8 failed builds. Can anyone help to accomplish a  successful build?

Comment: Could you share the exact error that you get from pipelines?

Comment: one thing you can definitely check although it doesn't likely matter is the indentation of your file. Secondly, could you post the error or the logs? It'd be easier to help look at what the problem is if we were able to see the exact error that happens.

Answer (score 0):

Testing database or any other 3rd party application should be done using integration Test not unit test, if you're trying to test the database with a unit test it with fail for sure because you're not implemting the proper connection before running the test which should be done only with an integration test.

Also make sure to call bin/phpunit in the right directory, you should cd to the main test directory in laravel and then do `../vendor/bin/phpunit Unit`.

Comment: Hi Asem, I wanted to perform Continuous Integration (CI) to build the application using docker image but it failed. I didn't use Unit Test.

Comment: Well it's in your code "vendor/bin/phpunit", the whole point of continues integration is building the code in order to be tested before deploying, if you want to do so only to deploy without testing then you have to remove the part where you run unit tests, after that it shoud work without issues, good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

**This is where the build failed**.

The problem was the composer. The composer was successfully installed but failed to run as shown in the datails below:

```
+ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin -- 
filename=composer
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...
Composer (version 1.9.0) successfully installed to: /usr/local/bin/composer
Use it: php /usr/local/bin/composer

+ composer install
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages. 

Problem 1
- This package requires php ^7.2 but your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that 
requirement.

Problem 2
- Installation request for moontoast/math 1.1.2 -> satisfiable by 
moontoast/math[1.1.2].
- moontoast/math 1.1.2 requires ext-bcmath * -> the requested PHP extension bcmath is 
missing from your system.

Problem 3
- Installation request for sebastian/type 1.1.3 -> satisfiable by 
sebastian/type[1.1.3].
- sebastian/type 1.1.3 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not 
satisfy that requirement.

Problem 4
- doctrine/lexer 1.1.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not 
satisfy that requirement.
- doctrine/lexer 1.1.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not 
satisfy that requirement.
- Installation request for doctrine/lexer 1.1.0 -> satisfiable by 
doctrine/lexer[1.1.0].
```

[image]

**Now build succeeded when removed my previous code and tested the "Hello word" string.**

as shown below:

```
echo "Hello world!"
<1s 
Build teardown
<1s
Searching for test report files in directories named [test-results, failsafe-reports, 
test-reports, surefire-reports] down to a depth of 4
Finished scanning for test reports. Found 0 test report files.
Merged test suites, total number tests is 0, with 0 failures and 0 errors.
```

[image]